# How to pass special characters (åöä) in Curl POST request?

Tags: curl, post, special-characters, urlencode

I am with a very high impact and stupid issue while sending Curl commands (via Windows) with special characters. It regards to -F "name=Anstalld"

**This works perfectly:**
C:\Services\CURL\curl.exe -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer 61b27a0ba58125d7ae36a77358973cb" -i -F "companyId=112" -F "name=**Anstalld**" -F "privilegeIds[]=211" -F "privilegeIds[]=1168" -F "description=Role" https://uri/roles?
But, the problem is that I need to be able to use inside the parameters, special characters like åöä, and can't figure out how to do it.

**This doesn't work:**
C:\Services\CURL\curl.exe -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer 61b27a0ba58125d7ae36a77358973cb" -i -F "companyId=112" -F "name=**Anställd**" -F "privilegeIds[]=211" -F "privilegeIds[]=1168" -F "description=Role" https://uri/roles?
How can I pass over these characters? Many thanks!

Curl Version 7.61.1 (x86_64-pc-win32) libcurl/7.61.1 OpenSSL/1.1.0i (WinSSL) zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.5 WinIDN libssh2/1.8.0 nghttp2/1.33.0
Release-Date: 2018-09-05

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Encode special characters and send them as data ascii. C:\Services\CURL\curl.exe uri -X POST -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" -H "Authorization: Bearer ***" -i --data-ascii "companyId=xx&description=xx&privilegeIds[]=xx&name=Employee%20%C3%A5%20%C3%B6%20%C3%A4%20%C3%85%20%C3%96%20%C3%84" –